# Data manipulation for heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I have a dataset that has 15 minute interval data. What I need to do is group the data by day/hour, averaging the 4 (15 min intervals) for each hour.

For example, take the 6:00, 6:15, 6:30, 6:45 values and average them to make one 6 AM value.

I'm looking for a general strategy on how to approach this and/or examples that may be me get on the right track (using JS, and/or lodash, moment)

```
[
{date:"2019-07-02T06:00:00.000Z",value:1271.22}
{date:"2019-07-02T06:15:00.000Z",value:1771.41},
{date:"2019-07-02T06:30:00.000Z",value:1780.83},
{date:"2019-07-02T06:45:00.000Z",value:1788.13},
{date:"2019-07-02T07:00:00.000Z",value:1805.31},
{date:"2019-07-02T07:15:00.000Z",value:1781.83},
{date:"2019-07-02T07:30:00.000Z",value:1764.17},
{date:"2019-07-02T07:45:00.000Z",value:1721.44},
{date:"2019-07-02T08:00:00.000Z",value:1712.92},
{date:"2019-07-02T08:15:00.000Z",value:1764.63},
{date:"2019-07-02T08:30:00.000Z",value:1759.03},
{date:"2019-07-02T08:45:00.000Z",value:1754.27},
{date:"2019-07-02T09:00:00.000Z",value:1745.81}
....
]
```

example data set here:
[Full example dataset here](https://codepen.io/esiason14/pen/oNbqqpQ?editors=0010)

yAxis will be [
'Saturday',
'Friday',
'Thursday',
'Wednesday',
'Tuesday',
'Monday',
'Sunday'
]

yAxis labels will be the times of day: (12 AM, 1 AM, 2 AM, 3 AM, etc)

like this:
[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk7jf.jpg[/img]

final data structure should look like this. This is broken down by hour (the average of the four points listed above), day of week, and value

```
[
[1, 6, 553],
[2, 6, 777],
[3, 6, 654],
[4, 6, 613],
[5, 6, 551],
[6, 6, 668],
[7, 6, 647],
[8, 6, 725],
[9, 6, 703],
[10, 6, 661],
[11, 6, 745],
[12, 6, 670],
[13, 6, 770],
[14, 6, 763],
[15, 6, 705],
[16, 6, 713],
[17, 6, 693],
[18, 6, 724],
[19, 6, 724],
[20, 6, 701],
[21, 6, 710],
[22, 6, 656]
....]
```

The last value is the average of the hour of that day. For example,

```
{date:"2019-07-02T06:00:00.000Z",value:1271.22} {date:"2019-07-02T06:15:00.000Z",value:1771.41}, {date:"2019-07-02T06:30:00.000Z",value:1780.83}, {date:"2019-07-02T06:45:00.000Z",value:1788.13}
```

On July 2nd, the 6AM average value would equal the average of the 4 values above

So for the entry in the final data structure it would be something like:

```
[hour of day, day of week, the average of the four intervals within that hour]
```

Comment: Hello,I do not understand your last array what should it be ? 1 means 1 AM, 6 means Sunday/saturday, and the last is the avg ? of all days ? just that day?

Comment: @Carlos1232 Correct. 1 is 1 AM, 6 is Sunday.

Comment: added clarification at the bottom of the post above

Comment: Can you Use Moment ? or just Native js.

Comment: Yes, moment is fine for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For approaching it first what we need to do is to groupBy the period of time it means Day-Hour, we do it with the following code->

```
let byHour = {};

const groups = (() => {
const byDay = (item) => moment(item.date).format('MMM DD YYYY'),
    forHour = (item) => moment(item.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:ss');
return {
    byDay,
    forHour
};
})();
const currentGroup = 'forHour';
let obj = _.groupBy(values, groups[currentGroup]);
let valuesGrouped = Object.values(obj)
```

For doing it we need moment and Lodash, what we do is we format the dates incoming and group them by Day-hour, we make them as keys, after we group them what we want is their values, once we have the values, format it as []

```
 let answerArr = valuesGrouped.map((a,i,arr)=>{
  
 return [moment(a[0].date).format('hh a'),moment(a[0].date).format('DD'),a.reduce((x, y) => parseInt(x) + parseInt(y.value),0) / a.length]
 }) 
 console.log(answerArr)
```

***PS***: Rembember that you are using ISO8601 as format once you format wich moment you will format it to your local timeZone.

***Offtopic***
In my case when I formatted it it started since june 30 22:00

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/Carlos1232/pen/RwrMYOV)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use this logic to achieve wanted output:

```
let finalOutput = [],
        curOutput = 0,
        startDay = 1,
        startHour = 4;

values.forEach((v, i) => {
    curOutput += v.value;
    i = i + 1;
    if (i % 4 === 0) {
        console.log(i)
        finalOutput.push([startHour, startDay, curOutput / 4])
        startHour += 1;
        curOutput = 0;
        
        if (startHour === 24) {
            startDay += 1;
            startHour = 0;
        }
    }
})

console.log(finalOutput)
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ut1yzx6s/